# Managing lifecycle for IP client application

Tags: android, network-programming, lifecycle

I have IP client application which has the following objects:

1. `Socket` instance connected to IP server.
2. `Thread` instance, executing `ThreadFunction`. This function continuously reads the socket, when it is connected.

Now I am trying to understand, what should I do, when activity is recreated (for example, after changing screen orientation). Is `Socket` instance lost? What happens with `ThreadFunction`? Looking at the other side behavior (IP server), I see that the client, Android application, is not disconnected. So, what should be my strategy in this case: should I create these resources again, or try to restore them by some way?

Comment: Why not run all of this in a service? Then you don't have the problem of Activity destruction.

Comment: @AedonEtLIRA - because I didn't learn a services yet :) I will try to implement this advice later, for now, I want to get consistent behavior in this application. Thanks.

Comment: Yup. :) Services will be exactly what you need for this situation. They are designed to handle any long term background action. Socket IO is definitely a background operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your question related to what happens to the resources when the application is destroyed, is that everything goes away, including sockets and runnables.

Even from the server side, the socket will be gone as soon as the server try to communicate over it.

Your best solution, as said already is to manage it using a service. It's quite similar to use an activity, and I encorage you to see a couple of examples.

If you realy want to make what you have now consistent without using a service, you may disable the screen rotation adding `android:configChanges="orientation"` to `AndroidManifest.xml`

Comment: Thanks. I think about disconnecting in onSaveInstanceState and saving the current state (like IP address and port) in the Bundle. When activity is recreated, I want to connect again, using Bundle information. Is it OK?

Comment: Of course, I understand that service is the real solution, but I still want to finish this program.

Comment: It should be fine. Just have in mind that you have to make your application deal with this reconnections on both sides (server and client) if client identity is to be kept, as communication will move to a new pair of sockets.

Comment: Thanks. The server is running on embedded device (not mobile), so in Android I only need to write a client code.

Comment: @Alex Farber I should have mentioned that for the specific case of device orientation change, you can use `onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()` to return one object that will be passed to the new activity when recreated. You could used it, to pass the socket (or the thread managing the socket) to the new activity, without the need of reconnecting.

Comment: Thanks, but this method is deprecated - like 90% Android API in every new Release :(

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using a [Service](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html). It is designed to do what you are asking.